# GridGain template searches

Tags: java, in-memory, gridgain

does anyone knows whether there is any possibility to implement template searching of objects stored in-memory data grid with GridGain? Let's consider the following. You have these classes:

```
class Employee{
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 private Address address;
 private Account account;
}

class Account{
 private Long id;
 private String accountNr;
}

class Address{
 private String street;
 private String postcode;
 private String city;
 private Country country;
}
```

then you have a search template like this:

```
Address address = new Address(null, null, "New York", null);
Employee template = new Employee(null, null,address, null);
grid.read(template);
```

- this will find all Employees living in New York. Is there any possibility to implement this within GridGain? If so, could you advice how?
  I was considering the sql joins to perform this operation however I need to create such a query at runtime and always with different amount of parameters after Where clause... and I am not able to solve this.

I will be thankful for any help/hint.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
public class Address {
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField(unique = true)
    private long id;
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField
    private String street;
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField
    private String postcode;
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField
    private String city;
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField
    private Country country;
}

public class Employee {
    @GridCacheQuerySqlField(unique=true)
    private long id;

    @GridCacheQuerySqlField
    private long addressId; // Address ID.

    // Not indexed.
    private String name;
}
```

And then do the query:

```
GridCacheQuery<Map.Entry<Long, Employee>> qry = cache.queries().createSqlQuery(Employee.class,
    "from Employee, Address where Employee.addressId = Address.id " +
        "and Address.name = ?");
// Query all nodes to find all cached CompanyZ employees in New York
qry.execute("CompanyZ","New York");
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately this will not solve my problem with creation of such a query in runtime. If you consider thta Employee class has 30 field and you need to be able to search with/without any of these fields, how to construct proper amount of parameters for qry.execute(1 to n) at runtime?

Comment: I think it's possible to construct such a query. However, perhaps you should also consider full-scan query with a Java predicate.